# Kendo Grid groupHeaderTemplate not calling function

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am attempting to call a function in kendo template.  I can do so when it is part of the item template of a row.  When I place the same code in the groupHeaderTemplate though, it doesn't seem to call the function.  Here is a link for you to see it in action:  http://dojo.telerik.com/uNabO

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, and here is the solution:  http://www.telerik.com/forums/groupheadertemplate-angular-compile

It appears that it was a bug in Kendo and has been updated in the latest release.

Working demo here:  http://dojo.telerik.com/uNabO/3